# Which aircraft is depicted on 1941 U.S. Post Office airmail stamps?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, aircraft-identification

Between June 25, 1941 and October 29, 1941 a tri-tailed “*Twin Motored Transport Plane*” was featured on U.S. airmail stamps in 6-, 8-, 10-, 15-, 20- and 50-cent dominations.

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.vistastamps.com/itm/us-stamp-c-air-mail-c28-transport-plane-15-1941)</sup>

Was the aircraft featured on those stamps an actual aircraft, or was it a Postal Service graphic artist’s conceptualization of one?

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be only an artist's conception and is an amalgam of several different designs, but apparently largely based on the [Douglas DC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-3) aircraft, the [Lockheed Electra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Model_10_Electra), and the [Beech 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Model_18).

[image]

The livery bears a striking resemblance to American Airline's DC-3 sleeper service, which operated during that era.

[image]

http://usstampgallery.com/view.php?id=1021c6191539bc1ca404bccf78595b7fdc0f06fd

Comment: The tail is also reminiscent of the [DC-4E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-4E)

Comment: Excellent comment.  The fuselage section above the engine has definitely been taken from the DC-4E -- in particular note the small rectangular windows just above each of the main cabin's windows.

Comment: YouTube has several very good taxiing, in-flight, and information videos of/on Douglas' experimental DC-4E and the subsequent sale of that prototype to Japan where it was used as a prototype for a Japanese WWII  4-engine bomber.